# query post to different role users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is it possible to show different posts to a different role users?? I need something like this

User A => Post A ||

User B => Post B

I can't use UserID, because there will be a lot of users. I was thinking something like this

```
<?php
if ( is_userA_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome A user!'; //here comes the query
} elseif ( is_userB_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome B user!'; // here comes the query
}
?>
```

I was reading on the codex but I only found the `is_admin()`, how can I call a new role?

I'd create the new roles in the functions.php with

```
    <?php 
add_role('userA', 'User A', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function.

```
if ( current_user_can( $role ) )
    $q = get_query();
```

Also, check functions like [`get_currentuserinfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) and [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata).